# Transform ellipse back to circle

Tags: geometry, transformation

I have a circle in a $xz$ plane with its center at Origin $O$ as shown in the diagram. The circle is being observed by a camera from point $C$ at $yz$ plane at an angle $\beta$ with the $z-$ Axis.

[image]

From the cameras perspective, the circle appears like an ellipse  and the actual radius $OP$ appears to be shorter and at an angle $P^{*}OQ$ with the $x-$ Axis. Is it possible to find the actual radius from this angle $P^{*}OQ$ and the length of reduced radius?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, because the overall scale depends on $OC$, the distance from the (center of the) circle to the camera.

Comment: Do you know the actual location of the camera center or only the angle $\beta$?

Comment: only the angle $\beta$

Comment: In that case, you don’t have enough information for the reconstruction, as Nominal Animal said.